# Where are annotations stored in class file

Tags: java, annotations, bytecode

I am trying to instrument a class file, but I was just wondering where annotations are stored in the class file format.  I tried putting them in the interface table however, when I did that it only recognized them as an interface not as an annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are stored in the `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations` and `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations` attributes for classes and <strike>methods</strike> class members, and the `RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations` and `RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations` attributes for method parameters.  You can find more detailed information about the classfile format in the [Java VM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: Fields can also have annotations.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to understand Java bytecode, a good starting point is writing in plain Java the class you would like to create using bytecode. Compile it, then use tools to retrieve generated bytecode.

Here's some tools I can think of :

- ASM's [Textifier](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/Textifier.html) (this class has a `main` method to make it easy to run)
- Intellij IDEA `Show bytecode` view
- [Bytecode outline](http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/) plugin for Eclipse

Comment: i am alreasy using jclasslib to look at generated byteocde